# how to save an array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I currently have this code, it saves in localstorage, but it generates several objects, I would like to store everything in a single array

```
getItemById(id) {
return this.cacheS.getOrSetCache(`StoreService_getItemById_${id}_${this.layout.emp.id}`, this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`), 300000);
}

  getOrSetCache(key: string, request: Observable<any>, msToExpire = 3600000): Observable<any> {
let cache: any = {};

cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

return (cache?.data && (cache?.exp > Date.now())) ?
  of(cache.data) :
  request.pipe(tap(v => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({data: v, exp: (Date.now() + msToExpire)}));
  }));
}
```

[image]

This code works, but I wanted to join all the `StoreService_getItemById_`, with this code it makes the array in a single `StoreService_getItemById_`, if you notice the image has several local storage with the name StoreService_getItemById_, I would like it to have only one and inside that it had the objects in array format

```
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({data: [v], exp: (Date.now() + msToExpire)}));
```

I wish it were the same "item"
[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to be trying to store an observable in localStorage..? That’s not going to work.

Comment: @MikeOne I updated my answer, it saves, but it saves several objects, I wanted to save everything in a single array

Comment: Okay.. the format you have for ‘v’ seems logical. How would you like the array to look like?

Comment: @MikeOne StoreService_getItemById_:[{id: 7518, ecommerce_id: null,}]
could have several objects inside the array

Comment: Maybe something like […v.data] when you store it?

Comment: @MikeOne where exactly should I put the […v.data] ?
I couldn't understand this part, sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: Slightly different I see: setItem(key, JSON.stringify({data: […v,] exp: (Date.now() + msToExpire)})); should do it?

Comment: @MikeOne it worked but not the way i wanted, i updated my question for you to see, now i believe it is clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to append items to an **array** in local storage. The thing is, local storage only saves **strings**. You can parse the string to convert it into an array, append a new item, then overwrite the old string.

```js
const key = 'my-array-key';
const someData = { name: 'name', id: 'abcdef' };
const msToExpire = 5000;

// Convert string to array, initializes empty array if string is empty
let arr: any[] = [];
let string = localStorage.getItem(key);
if (string) arr = JSON.parse(string);

// Push a new item and overwrite the old string
arr.push({data: someData, exp: (Date.now() + msToExpire)});
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(arr));
```

I'm not really sure how you want to structure that function but this example should give you the general idea.

Comment: what happened to a "cache" variable?

Comment: @LeonardoLima yeah I'm not really sure what you want to do there, I edited my answer to give you the general idea.

Comment: your answer is good, I tested it here, it worked, but how could I map the ones that are already saved?
In my function I was able to map them, I will mark your answer as the best!

Comment: whenever a product id is already saved in localstorage it will not make the getItemById request again, that was the idea and also if the expiration date has expired